# How to hide button on the Jquery UI dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, dialog

I have been using JQuery UI dialog box.The following code I am using.Can any one please let me know how to hide the Export button after click

```
$( "#dialog-confirm1" ).dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height:350,
            width:650,
            modal: false,
            autoOpen:false,
            buttons: {
                "Export": function() {
                    exportCSV(2);


                },
                Cancel: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: When you say "hide the Export button", you mean leave the dialog box open with only the cancel button?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use `$('.ui-button:contains(Export)').hide()`: (the following code hides the export button when you click it)

```
$( "#dialog-confirm1" ).dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height:350,
            width:650,
            modal: false,
            autoOpen:false,
            buttons: {
                "Export": function() {
                    exportCSV(2);
                    $(event.target).hide();


                },
                Cancel: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Hi,Nicola Thanks, it works.But forgot to tell.I do have two dialog boxes dialog-confirm1 and dialog-confirm0 and both have "Export" button and when I click Export button of dialog-confirm1 dialog box it also hides Export button of dialog-confirm dialog box.Thanks, Ravi

Comment: @Ravi i think that the better option is what Frédéric Hamidi pointed out, use event.target (i updated my answer to use it)

Comment: event.target goes to the span inside the button, not the button itself. Use: $(event.target).parent().hide(); instead.

Answer (score 4):

The [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#option-buttons) for the `buttons` option says:

> The context of the callback is the dialog element; if you need access
>   to the button, it is available as the target of the event object.

Therefore, you can use [event.target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) to refer to the button element:

```
buttons: {
    "Export": function(event) {
        $(event.target).hide();
        exportCSV(2);
    },
    "Cancel": function() {
        $(this).dialog("close");
    }
}
```

Comment: Use $(event.target).parent().hide(); instead. At least for me, the target is the span inside the button.

Answer (score 0):

```
buttons: [{
    "Export": function() { exportCSV(2); },
    click: $( this ).hide()

}]
```